# Specify number of loops for animated GIF (ImageMagick)?

Tags: image-transforms, craft-features, gif

I'm experimenting with Craft 2.6, and am having a bit of difficulty with animated GIFs. The original animated GIF files I'm working with are set up to only loop once, but when I upload them into Craft and they're processed, the resulting GIFs loop infinitely.

Craft is running locally on my Mac, and I've made sure that ImageMagick is installed and working via MAMP and PHP 5.6.

Is this something that could be added as a feature to Craft 2 (having it check for the original number of loops in the GIF file, then recreating it with the same value)?  Or is that already in the works for Craft 3 and not in the cards for version 2?  :)  Thanks!

Comment: I'd say this is 70% bug, 30% feature request. :) Can you send the animated GIF over to support@craftcms.com and we'll see what we can do about it?  Either way, going to go ahead and vote to close this one as a bug.

Comment: Absolutely -- email sent! Happy to help troubleshoot, just let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Did you found out a solution for this issue?

Comment: @william The Craft team released an update to Craft to address the issue the very next day.  We can't specify how many loops a gif has, but an imported animated gif will now have the same number of loops as it did when you started (so single-loop gifs will no longer loop infinitely after being imported to Craft).