# Uploaded .gif only loops once instead of infinitely

Tags: image-transforms, image, upload, loop, gif

Having a problem where uploading an infinitely looping gif only loops once.

I've tested it with and without image transforms and get the same issue.
I know there there was an issue previously stated here 
[Specify number of loops for animated GIF (ImageMagick)?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/16569/specify-number-of-loops-for-animated-gif-imagemagick) and that was fixed in a recent release. Any thoughts on what the issue could be?

Craft CMS 2.6.2931 (multilingual)

ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 (dev)

ImageMagick 6.7.8-9 (staging)

Comment: This looks to be a bug. Going to vote to close here and respond in the support tickets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the same problem here. I downgraded to version 2.6.2922 for testing purposes and the gif loops infinitely again. I suspect the bugfix in 2.6.2923
"Fixed a bug where animated GIF loop limits were not being respected." to be responsible. Unfortunately a downgrade on production is currently not possible for us, since the Schema version changed...

Comment: Thanks @jakob-o at least I know where the problem is now. Hopefully they fix it soon.

Comment: Did either of you report this bug to support@craftcms.com? Downgrading does not seem like an acceptable solution.

Comment: I sent a request via the admin panel, no non-automated reply yet, though.
EDIT: Got a response.